# Converting Excel function result from text to A1 range without VBA

Tags: excel, function, return-value, formula

I am using `ADDRESS` in a formula to calculate remaining days, my problem is that the `ADDRESS` returns a text string `"A1"` and not `A1`. I think I can remember that there was a known solution for that, but I was not able to find it.

```
=DAY(TODAY()-ADDRESS(ROW();(MONTH(TODAY())+1)))
```

`ADDRESS` returns `"A1"` and not as needed `A1`, same result with `R1C1`.

Comment: Simple answer - `Indirect()`

Comment: Thanks, I read through `INDIRECT`, guess I interpreted it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer, copy of a Comment from @John Bustos:

> Simple answer - `Indirect()`